# Content deployment: enterprise edition to standard edition

Tags: content-deployment

Our staging environment has Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise edition installed. We are not using any features specific to this edition. The production server has only Standard edition installed. We'd like to use content deployment to move content from staging to production.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just content deployment you should be ok. For site/list definitions, object model code, or other "infrastructure" type customizations, you should be cautious. It is always ideal for your staging environment to match your production environment.

Comment: Have you attempted this, or can you point me towards some documentation? Thanks.

Comment: While content deployment can mean a lot of things, here is Microsoft's documentation to get you started: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263428.aspx. I can't say as we have attempted targeting a  production server with a different SharePoint edition on it. We support clients that use every edition of SharePoint. We learned early on that it is wise to test on a machine that matched production as closely as possible, so virtualization has become our best friend. You would be better off if both environments matched, or maybe even if staging were Standard Ed and production Enterprise.

Comment: We talked to MS on this one. Like you said, it's fine as long as you're not targeting enterprise features.

Comment: MS is actually incorrect. See this question I asked (with my new account), and my solution: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13698/export-import-spweb-problem-with-dataconnectionlibrary-feature