# export / import spweb problem with DataConnectionLibrary feature

Tags: 2010, powershell, import, export

I'm attempting to export a subsite from staging to production using powershell and export-spweb and import-spweb.

This worked just fine from staging to development.

When we try to run this on production, we get the following error:

**Could not find Feature DataConnectionLibrary**

We have disabled this feature on staging and tried again, but were are getting the same error message.

We're moving from Enterprise to Standard if that's of any consequence. And 2010 on both servers.

Thanks.

**Update**

I found this posting. Turns out that it really does matter when moving from enterprise to standard, even if you're not using the features.

I found this url:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/a2150fcd-16e2-4583-8862-8c7adecc9bdc

It uses stsadm. In powershell, I have the following. Hopefully this helps someone else.

**site collection level**

```
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url -Identity IPFSSiteFeatures
```

**site collection level: not active anyway**

```
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url -Identity PremiumSite
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url -Identity BizAppsCTypes
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url -Identity BizAppsFields
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url -Identity ExcelServerSite
```

**subsite level**

```
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url/subsite -Identity DataConnectionLibrary
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url/subsite -Identity BizAppsSiteTemplates
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url/subsite -Identity ReportListTemplate
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url/subsite -Identity PremiumWeb
```

**subsite level: not active anyway**

```
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url/subsite -Identity BizAppsListTemplates
Disable-SPFeature -url http://url/subsite -Identity IPFSWebFeatures
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you use Get-SPFeature to verify that the feature was successfully deactivated before re-exporting? Maybe you need to use the -force parameter on Disable-SPFeature. Also, make sure the -url parameter is for the site and not the site collection, since this feature is web scoped.

Comment: I noticed in the log that the feature was included - because there are piles of subsites under the site I'm exporting. I found a script to deactivate all of these. Does the -force at the top level cascade to subsites? That would have been nice. Turns out there are other features that need to be turned off as well. I'll update my question.